# Expected ";" before "WebView" in Xcode

Tags: xcode, webkit, browser, webview, void

I am trying to follow the basic WebKit tutorial provided on Apple's Mac Dev site:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html

I am at the part where I update my title to the current page's title and update the URL to the current URL. However, when I try to Build this:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame //2 errors on this line stating: expected ")" before "WebView" and expected ")" before "WebFrame"
{
//Only report feedback from main frame.
if (frame == [sender mainFrame]) {
    NSString *url = [[[[frame provisionalDataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
    [textField setStringValue:url];
}
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didRecieveTitle:(NSString *)title forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame // Same 2 errors as the first line of code
{
if (frame == [sender mainFrame]){
    [[sender window] setTitle:title];
}
}
```

Could somebody please tell me what is wrong with this? It is the *exact* code as Apple's example.

--Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Did your right click on "frameworks" and click "Add existing Framework" and add Webkit.framework?

Did you include the include files?

Comment: Thank you, tmiddlet, for the fast response! I did add the WebKit.framework however, I don't think that I included the included files. Do I include in the .h or the .m, and what files should I include from the WebKit.framework?